# Android resource loading

Tags: android

Does android all deflate images in the apk when it first runs?

For example, I have different `.png`s in a drawable directory. When does android deflate images and load them in memory?

Does it only do it when I execute the code like:

```
imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.myimage)
```

Comment: When you say "Does it only do it when..." what exactly do you mean by "only"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's exactly when they get "deflated", whenever you reference an drawable resource from R.java.